# How to update multiple marker location simultaneously using JSON data? Leaflet JS

Tags: javascript, json, dictionary, leaflet

I'm using [Leaflet JS](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html) to build an interactive map viewer that can track movement of multiple devices. And I'm using JSON data to set Latitude and Longitude for every marker.

The JSON data looks like this:

```
{"BMS":[{"id":"PR01","type":"prajurit","lat":"-6.248008","long":"107.004158"},{"id":"PR02","type":"prajurit","lat":"-6.224084","long":"106.653069"},{"id":"PR03","type":"kendaraan","lat":"-6.244316","long":"106.649734"}]}
```

The data contains position information from 3 devices.

I already successfully set the markers based on latitude and longitude of the devices with a `for` loop. But I can't manage to update the movement of marker with `setLatLng` and with a `for` loop. I don't want to use the clear layer function to add a new marker every time I get a location update, because I need to save the movement history of each device for later. What should I do to make it work? Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Here is my code. `setInterval` is meant to run the code continously. And I tried to use array variables as the marker variable, and to tag every marker (since using windows[variable_name] is bad practice).

```
window.setInterval(function(){

    ++z;
    //alert(z);

    function doSomething(data){
        jsonBmsData = JSON.parse(data);

    }

    $.get('get_jsondata.php', doSomething);

    if(z == 1){

        for(var i=0; i<jsonBmsData.BMS.length; ++i){

            marker[i][0] = jsonBmsData.BMS[i].id;
            marker[i][1] = jsonBmsData.BMS[i].type;
            marker[i][2] = jsonBmsData.BMS[i].lat;
            marker[i][3] = jsonBmsData.BMS[i].long;

            markerMove[i] = L.marker([marker[i][2],marker[i][3]])
            .bindPopup('ID Prajurit = ' + marker[i][0] + '<br>Tipe = ' + marker[i][1]
            + '<br>Lat = ' + [marker[i][2] + '<br>Long = ' + marker[i][3])
            .addTo(map);

        }

    } else if(z > 1){

        for(var j=0; j<jsonBmsData.BMS.length; ++j){

            marker[j][0] = jsonBmsData.BMS[j].id;
            marker[j][1] = jsonBmsData.BMS[j].type;
            marker[j][2] = jsonBmsData.BMS[j].lat;
            marker[j][3] = jsonBmsData.BMS[j].long;

            var newLatLng = new L.latLng(marker[j][2],marker[j][3]);

            markerMove[j].setLatLng(newLatLng).update();
            markerMove[j]._popup.setContent('ID Prajurit = ' + marker[j][0] + '<br>Tipe = ' + marker[j][1]
            + '<br>Lat = ' + [marker[j][2] + '<br>Long = ' + marker[j][3]);

        }

    }

},50);
```

Comment: Ehm, and what is the problem about? Your second loop is not working? Calling `markerMove[j].setLatLng(newLatLng).update();` is not working? I see that in your second loop, you initialized `j=0`, in condition you use `i`, but the `j` variable is never upadated.

Comment: @xxxmatko, Thank you for the correction. I edited the code. Yes, `markerMove[j].setLatLng(newLatLng).update();` didn't give me any result. Did i do it wrong? Need your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use an object to store markers with their id as propertyname and the marker as the property value. It will makes things a lot easier. To store the previous positions you can add a array to each marker to store them. Here in code with comments to explain:

```
// The object to store markers
var markers = {};

// Function for setting/updating markers
function setMarkers(data) {

  // Loop over the BMS array and handle each object
  data.BMS.forEach(function (obj) {

    // Check if there is already a marker with that id in the markers object
    if (!markers.hasOwnProperty(obj.id)) {
      // No marker with that id found in the markers object

      // Create it, and add it to the map, store into markers object
      markers[obj.id] = new L.Marker([obj.lat, obj.long]).addTo(map);

      // Add array to the marker instance to store the previous latlngs
      markers[obj.id].previousLatLngs = [];

    } else {
      // There is already a marker with that id in the markers object

      // Store the previous latlng
      markers[obj.id].previousLatLngs.push(markers[obj.id].getLatLng());

      // Set new latlng on marker
      markers[obj.id].setLatLng([obj.lat, obj.long]);
    }
  });
}
```

And here's a working example on Plunker; http://plnkr.co/edit/HrrnXh?p=preview

There is a very cool plugin for Leaflet, called Realtime. It does exacty what you want and more but it expects a GeoJSON collection as data, so it won't work with your dataset. If you are able to convert your data to a GeoJSON collection, it's really worth to take a look at:

GeoJSON: http://geojson.org/

Demo: http://www.liedman.net/leaflet-realtime/

Repo: https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-realtime

Comment: Very thank you! It's beautiful! I didn't think the work can be done with object, you enlighten me! And yes, maybe it is a bad idead using array to do the work, since i keep getting undefined array error. It is making me frustated since there is no tutorial or example to use object for this work. I'll try to apply this in my code. Thank you! You saved me!

Comment: No thanks, you're always welcome. An array object is just a fancy object which keeps track of it's length and has some extra functionality like a forEach method to loop over it's properties and lots more. See: [MDN Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#)  A normal object can have strings as keys, an array cannot. So in this case it comes in very handy. When using an array and you want to find a marker you need to do this: `markers.forEach(function(marker){if (marker.id == obj.id) {//found}})` but now you can simply do: `markers[obj.id]`

Comment: Just remembered there is a nice plugin for this, added that to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any error in calling `setLatLng` method, but I suppose that, there is an error in

```
var newLatLng = new L.latLng(marker[j][2],marker[j][3]);
```

When you want to create new long lat object you should call `new L.LatLng()` (with big L letter) or just `L.latLng()` which is a shortcut method to the same and it calls `new L.LatLong()` in the end. Check your property `newLatLng` if it is a correct object.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Yes, i already corrected it, and still didn't give me any result. Then, i tried to catch the error with a simpler code, and it said "markerMove[j] is undefined". I don't understand why it is undefined. Or maybe i am using array in wrong way than it should be?

Comment: Could you past the corrected code? And where is your `marker` and `markerMove` defined?

Comment: Here is the simpler code i'm using to check the error: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/gundargerm/z52wa9kb/1/). Check it, please. Thank you.